# No repository found http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3 but proxy set

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, repository

I'm trying to install new software in Eclipse (4.3/Kepler).  Although I'm getting errors on all update/install sites, I'm only asking about the subject because I know it *should* work.

The above URL for updating
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3

results in an Eclipse error log as mentioned at the end of this post.

There is a firewall, and I've gotten past it in other Java programs by setting -Dhttp.proxyHost= and -Dhttp.proxyPort.  The following simple test program completes without exception when the properties are set, and fails when they are not:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class TestProxy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL("http://java.com");
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

However, Eclipse does not care whether I put specify, manual, direct, or native.  It does not matter whether I give it a proxy host and port when it's manually configured.  It doesn't matter if I give it a username/password.  It just does not work.

To make matters worse, someone when designing this update paradigm decided to have it not verifiable in web browsers.  So it gives a cryptic message about how either the URL is wrong, or that it can't be done in a web browser.  Well, I know that.  I just want to verify the URL.  It would be better to put a HTML page that says, "Yes you've reached the right page."

To further complicate things, the internal web browser in Eclipse can access pages outside the firewall successfully.

Why?

...
    eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
    java.version=1.7.0_21
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

```
Error
Fri Jan 31 17:37:23 EST 2014
Provisioning exception

org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```